# Using AJAX and PHP to change onclick

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, onclick

I get the following errors when I run this simple AJAX code

- uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token
- uncaught reference error loaddoc is not defined .............when I press the button

From reading stackoverflow I am pretty sure my problem is with the 'onclick' but I cannot understand how to use the listener instead which I see is recommended to do.

My AJAX code is

```
<body>

    <a>Hello-first</a>

    <p id="trainblock">Can I change this</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="loaddoc()">Press</button>

    <script>
        function loaddoc()
        {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function();
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("trainblock").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","gettrains.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: In JavaScript you will get such error if line in or before this function has error.

Comment: Please check the onReadyStatuschange function call once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot "{}" after "function" : xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function();

change to :

```
function loaddoc() {
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
             document.getElementById( "trainblock" ).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open( "GET", "gettrains.php", true );
     xmlhttp.send();
 }
```